# Ext JS - Populate combobox using value from another Combobox from Database (SQL)

Tags: sql, json, extjs, combobox

I have two combobox, values are coming from database i am using json to populate the same. Second combo gets populated when the first combo changes. First time when we set the value of the first combo it works like magic. But second time, it does not get bind. and throws an error
This is my running code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function() {

 var serverStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  storeId: 'serverStore',
  fields: [
   {
    name: 'u_hostname',
    mapping: 'u_hostname',
    type: 'string'
   }
  ],
  proxy: {
   type: 'ajax',
   url: '/list/data/dbapi/getRecordData',
   extraParams: {
    type: 'table',
    useSql: true,
    sqlQuery: 'select distinct(u_hostname) from SCRIPT_SCHEDULE'
   },
   reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'records'
   }
  },
  autoLoad: true
 });
 
 
 var dpsStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    
  storeId: 'dpsStore',
  fields: [
   {
    name: 'u_username',
    mapping: 'u_username',
    type: 'string'
   },
   {
    name: 'u_hostname',
    mapping: 'u_hostname',
    type: 'string'
   }
  ],
  proxy: {
   type: 'ajax',
   url: '/list/data/dbapi/getRecordData',
   extraParams: {
    type: 'table',
    useSql: true,
  
   },
   reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'records'
   }
  },
  autoLoad: true
 });
 



    var dpsCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox',{
    id: 'dpsCombo',
    fieldLabel: 'Username',
    hidden: false,
    margin: '5 0 0 25',
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'u_username',
    displayField: 'u_username'
    

    });

  
   var serverCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox',{
    id: 'serverCombo',
    fieldLabel: 'Server Name',
    hidden: false,
    margin: '5 0 0 25',    
    store: serverStore,
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'u_hostname',
    displayField: 'u_hostname',
   listeners: {               
        change: changeStore
   }
});
    function changeStore(combo, value){
        var store;
        store = dpsStore;
        var combobox = Ext.getCmp('dpsCombo');
        combobox.clearValue();
        console.log(value);
        store.getProxy().setExtraParam("sqlQuery", `select distinct(u_username) from SCRIPT_SCHEDULE where u_hostname ='${value}'`);
        console.log(value);
        combobox.bindStore(store);
        store.load();
        

}

 Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
  id: 'processviewport',
  layout: 'border',
  items: [{
   xtype: 'panel',
   id: 'filterPanel',
   layout: 'hbox',
   title: 'Data filter',
   region: 'north',
   collapsible: true,
   items: [{
    xtype: 'panel',
    layout: 'hbox',
    flex: 2,
    items:[
     {
     xtype: 'panel',
     layout: 'vbox',
     items: [
      serverCombo,
      dpsCombo
     ]
    }]
   }]
  }]
 });
});

</script>
```

Error :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Comment: Which version of extjs are you using, which toolkit? Why ARE YOU WRITING SQL IN FRONTEND?

Comment: Hi @Arthur, thanks for writing. I have fixed the SQL but looks like the binding is an issue. I am writing SQL in frontend because this is not for any bigger application just a small front end UI to trigger a workflow automation.

Comment: May you provide working example in fiddle.sencha.com?

Comment: When we bind the combobox second time do we have to set anything ? I am having problem with binding the store at second change, first one after loading is working fine.

Comment: May you read the comments carefully?

Comment: May you provide working example in fiddle.sencha.com?  -- I will not be able to call the api and fill the data, hence cannot create the running code in sencha.

Answer (score 0):

The issue the combobox was not rendering data on the second change was resolved by adding lastQuery: field in the second combo.